# How do you pass a string value in PHP into a sqlsrv() datetime value?

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 form values that I concatenate to create a date of birth:

```
$b_dob = new DateTime($b_dob3."-".$b_dob1."-".$b_dob2);
```

And I'm trying to do an INSERT with this (datetime) value (which is part of an array):

```
$insertinapp[ 'b_dob' ] = date_format($b_dob, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And I keep getting this error:

The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Am I adding characters to the new DateTime string that make it invalid for date_format, or is the issue using date_format?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$b_dob = $b_dob3."-".$b_dob1."-".$b_dob2;    
$insertinapp[ 'b_dob' ] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($b_dob));
```